# Python Pandas - Group by an aggregate (count of conditional values)

Tags: python, pandas, count, aggregate, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame (roughly 3000 rows like below):

`df.index   q_id      total_paid choice_txt
3           176            6918          7
12          176               0          3
21          176            5053         10
30          176            5219          9
39          176            5622          8
48          176               0          7
57          176            4239          7
66          176            2811          7
75          176            5049          7
84          176            6797          3
93          176            1740          7
102         176            4747          9
111         176             882          8
120         176            5961          6
129         176            7959          6
138         176            7100          2
147         176            1565          2
156         176            5776          7
165         176            4385          1
174         176               0         10
183         176            1131          8
192         176           10586          7
201         176             920          7
210         176            1900          4
219         176            4436          1
228         176            8715          5
237         176            8248          7
246         176               0          6
255         176            7683         10
263         176             572          8
and on...`

I am having trouble grouping it by value counts. Essentially I want to take this DataFrame and group it by counts of identical 'choice_txt', but also group 'total_paid' by value aggregates. In this case I want 3 aggregates (low set, hypothetically < 3000)(mid set, 3001-6000)(high set, 6001+)

In the example, 'choice_txt' is an identifier, not a count above. I would like to count how many identifiers exist for each one, in this case there are identifiers 1-10. In 3000 rows, I have one record for each identifier 1-10.

Grouped into a final result like this:

`q_id    total_paid  choice_txt            count

176       low            10                 1

          low            2                  3

          low            3                  2

          low            4                  1

          low            6                  5

          low            7                  4

          low            8                  3

          low            9                  2

          mid            10                 1

          mid            8                  1

          mid            1                  1

          high           10                 1

          high           2                  3

          high           3                  2

          high           4                  1

          high           6                  5

          high           7                  4

          high           8                  3

          high           9                  2`

My work so far got me to where I can group it well by actual total paid value:

`sub_grouped_df = filtered_df.groupby([series_col, breakout_column, "choice_txt"]).count()['another_column']
q_id       total_paid  choice_txt
176        0               10            1
                           2             3
                           3             2
                           4             1
                           6             5
                           7             4
                           8             3
                           9             2
           56              10            1
           236             8             1
           455             1             1
           572             8             1
           609             8             1
           636             7             1
           826             10            1
...
176        9096            4             1
           9141            5             1
           9232            5             1
           9357            8             1
           9371            3             1
           9601            1             1
           9604            2             1
           9706            8             1
           9719            1             1
           10032           1             1
           10490           9             1
           10586           7             1
           10632           3             1
           10799           4             1
           12437           1             1`

I have the grouping I need, except I need to take the 'total_paid' and group it by value (again the low/mid/high sets mentioned above.

But I can't figure out how to evaluate the total_paid col by value and use that into the group by.

EDIT:
OK I have a solution that works, but it seems like a total hack:
Since I have 3 groups that I need to accumulate (low,mid,high), separated my main data frame into 3 separate data frames by the low,mid,high criteria:

    `low_df = filtered_df.loc[filtered_df[breakout_column] <= low_high] 
    high_df = filtered_df.loc[filtered_df[breakout_column] > mid_high]

    mid_df = filtered_df.drop(low_df.index)
    mid_df = mid_df.drop(high_df.index)`

Then I grouby on each one to get the grouping I need:

    `sub_low_df = low_df.groupby([series_col, "choice_txt"])
    sub_mid_df = mid_df.groupby([series_col, "choice_txt"])
    sub_high_df = high_df.groupby([series_col, "choice_txt"])`

Finally I sequentially combine my results into a dict for reporting.
Is this an acceptable solution or is there a better way to achieve the result?

Comment: Please reformat the question properly and show us what you tried.

Comment: Done, I can group the data by the columns I want into a grouper object. But I know I need to group again by 'total_paid' and accumulate the counts on the last column further.